# Unable to call system('curl') from MATLAB 2013 a

Tags: linux, matlab, curl

Here is the experiment I tried on Ubunu 14.04.

```
curl -X POST -d '<request>something<\request>'  --header "Content-Type:application/xml" url
```

This command works on the terminal but it does not work as a MATLAB command using system(cmd) i.e.

```
cmd = 'curl -d ''<request>something<\request>'' url' ;
system(cmd)
```

here is the error message from MATLAB:

```
curl: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libcurl.so.4: 
no version information    available (required by curl)
curl: (48) An unknown option was passed in to libcurl
:1: parser error : Document is empty

^-:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found ^

ans = 1
```

I do not have any `libcurl.so` files except under `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/`.

```
sroot@ubuntu14:~$ ls /usr/lib/libcu*
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/libcu*: No such file or directory
sroot@ubuntu14:~$ ls /usr/local/lib/libcu*
ls: cannot access /usr/local/lib/libcu*: No such file or directory
```

Regards,

Comment: I think your error is "Document is empty" and "Start tag expected, '<' not found". libcurl.so is found, or otherwise you would not get this message.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu, the `libcurl*.so.*` are here

```
> $ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl*

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.3     
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-nss.so.4.2.0
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4     
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.3
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.2.0 
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-nss.so.3        
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.2.0
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-nss.so.4
```

And as for problem in calling curl from within matlab, you can redirect '`/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libcurl.so.4`' to '`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4`'.